# Matrix unit-vector multiplication and the resulting norm

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that $\|Ax\| = \|A\|\|x\|$ when $\|x\| = 1$ and why?

Comment: $\| A \| \| x \|$ is by definition as big as $\| Ax \|$ can be. For most $A$, $\| Ax \|$ varies depending on which direction $x$ points.

Comment: No and almost any example other than a multiple of the identity will show that this is not true.

Answer (score 2):

No, because by definition $\lVert A\rVert=\sup_{\lVert x\rVert=1}\lVert Ax\rVert$. Therefore your claim is not reasonable to expect.